# Debugging in Emacs: Triggering GUD commands from the buffer with the source code

Tags: python, emacs

When I am debugging code in Emacs, I like to have two buffers open, the first one with the **source code** I am debugging, and the second one with the **debugger** ([pdb](http://docs.python.org/library/pdb.html) for Python).

I have the following keyboard shortcuts defined on my `.emacs` file:

```
(require 'gud)                                                                                                                                                
(define-key gud-mode-map '[C-f10] 'gud-next)                                                                                                                  
(define-key gud-mode-map '[C-f11] 'gud-step)                                                                                                                  
(define-key gud-mode-map '[C-f5] 'gud-cont)                                                                                                                   
(define-key gud-mode-map '[C-f12] 'gud-break)
```

With the above, I can trigger the GUD shortcuts for `gud-next`, `gud-step`, etc. from the buffer where `pdb` is running, but I can't trigger them from the buffer that has the python code.

I would like to use keyboard shortcuts on the buffer with the **source code** to trigger GUD commands for the debugger. Is there any way to do this?

I am using the most recent version of [python-mode](https://launchpad.net/python-mode) (6.0.4) and Emacs 23.3.1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using global-set-key instead:

```
(global-set-key [C-f10] 'gud-next)
(global-set-key [C-f11] 'gud-step)
(global-set-key [C-f5] 'gud-cont)
(global-set-key [C-f12] 'gud-break)
```

IIRC, this worked for me.

Comment: Good point. Thanks, this works great. I wonder if `python-mode` has it's own keyboard map?